# SVG rect border, not stroke

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am making a d3 graph and trying to put a border around my rect elements. The rect elements are appended to a cell and the text elements are appended to the same cell. Thus if I change the stroke in the rect I lose all the text for some reason, and if I change the stroke in the cell the borders and fonts change too.

This is a portion of my code for drawing the graph.

```
this.svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")

          .attr("class", "chart")
          .style("position", "relative")
          .style("width", (this.w +this.marginTree.left+this.marginTree.right) + "px")
          .style("height", (this.h + this.marginTree.top + this.marginTree.bottom) + "px")
          .style("left", this.marginTree.left +"px")
          .style("top", this.marginTree.top + "px")
        .append("svg:svg")
          .attr("width", this.w)
          .attr("height", this.h)
        .append("svg:g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");


        this.node = this.root = this.nestedJson;



        var nodes = this.treemap.nodes(this.root)
            .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

        this.tip = d3.tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .html(function(d) {
                return "<span style='color:white'>" + (d.name+",\n "+d.size) + "</span>";
              })
        this.svg.call(this.tip);



        var cell = this.svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "cell")
            .call(this.position)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
            .on("click", function(d) { return this.zoom(this.node == d.parent ? this.root : d.parent); })
            .style("border",'black');

        var borderPath = this.svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", this.marginTree.left)
            .attr("y", this.marginTree.top)
            .attr("height", this.h - this.marginTree.top - this.marginTree.bottom )
            .attr("width", this.w - this.marginTree.left - this.marginTree.right)
            .style("stroke", 'darkgrey')
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke-width", '3px');


        cell.append("svg:rect")

            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "rect-" + (i+1); })
            .attr("class","highlighting2")
                .attr("title", function(d) {return (d.name+", "+d.size);})
                .attr("data-original-title", function(d) {return (d.name+",\n "+d.size);})
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy ; })
          .on('mouseover', this.tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', this.tip.hide)
          .style("fill", function(d) {return coloring(d.color);});


        cell.append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "treemap-text nameTexts") 
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "name-" + (i+1); })
            .attr("x", cellMargin)  
            .attr("y", function(d) {  return parseInt($('.treemap-text').css('font-size'))+cellMargin; })
          .text(function(d) {return (d.name);});

       cell.append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "treemap-text sizeTexts") 
            .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "size-" + (i+1); })  
            .attr("x", cellMargin)  
            .attr("y", function(d) {  return 2*parseInt($('.treemap-text').css('font-size'))+2*cellMargin; })
            .text(function(d) {return (d.size);});
```

Additionally, I thought about creating lines and drawing four lines around each rect element, but was wondering if there is an easier way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check fully through your source, it would also be helpful to work with jsbin, codepen, jsfiddle or other online platforms to show your problem.

Actually I think you just have misinterpreted the SVG presentation attributes and their styling with CSS. For SVG elements only SVG presentation attributes are valid in CSS. This means there is no border property as you have it in your code. Also note that for `<text>` elements the fill color is the font-body color and the stroke is the outline of the font. Consider that stroke and fill are inherited down to child element which means that if you have a rectangle with a stroke style and some containing text element that they will have the stroke applied as outline and you'd need to override the styles there.

Hope you can solve your issue.

Cheers
Gion